# Dask groupby MemoryError:

Tags: dask

I have a Parquet file with  over 1B records. 
I'm trying to run a `groupby`  with the following statement:

```
dfg =  df[['col1','col2','col3']].groupby(['col1','col2']]).count().compute()
```

I'm running with a `client` with the following configuration.
`client = distributed.Client(set_as_default=True)`

I get a `MemoryError:`

Should I be running with a different client configuration?

I'm running on a stand-alone workstation  with cores:24, Memory: 123 GB

BTW - At the end I need to save the `count` back to the original `df` as a new column.

Any suggestions? Should I run the `groupby` in a database rather then `Dask`?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, by any chance did you able to solve it? If yes, could you please elaborate your approach here?

Comment: Using Dask wasn't the best solution, we ended up using Spark or SQLlight

Answer (score 0):

The operation you're doing, `groupby(...).count()` should complete in a small amount of space.

The only possibility I see is that maybe your partitions are very large, and so having 24 of them in memory at once is problematic?

Sorry I can't be more helpful here.

Comment: So should I recreate the parquet with smaller partitions? if so - can `dask` have an option to do so (the `partition_on` parameter is not relevant). can  the configuration of the  `client.distribution` assist?

Comment: I don't know that this is your problem.  It's just a blind guess.

Comment: Just for the record - On a Single machine with 24 cores and 123 GB memory we were not able to perform the `group by` for 2.5 Billion records in `Dask` and we had to move to  `SQL SERVER`.   BTW the machine has 192GB RAM but the `dask cluster` was not able to identify all the RAM.